# Inject AWS Codebuild Environment Variables into Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Is there a way to pass AWS Codebuild environment variables into a Dockerfile?
I'd like to be able to pull from ECR like this:

`FROM $My_AWS_ACCOUNT.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someimage:latest`

Where `$My_AWS_ACCOUNT` references an environment variables within my codebuild project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use `FROM ${My_AWS_ACCOUNT}.xxx`. My_AWS_ACCOUNT should be passed as an argument to the docker build.
This is how I would do it:

`ARG My_AWS_ACCOUNT=SOME_DEFAULT_IMAGE
FROM ${My_AWS_ACCOUNT}.xxx`

When you build:
`docker build --build-arg My_AWS_ACCOUNT=${My_AWS_ACCOUNT}`

Comment: Just a side note on the buildspec.yml file itself, both ${ENV_VAR} and $ENV_VAR syntax are valid. Also, as i was struggling a bit on it, to pass multiples build-args to docker build command, you just need to rewrite the args with another variables. 

E.g : `docker build --build-arg DOCKER_VAR_1=${CODEBUILD_VAR_1} --build-arg DOCKER_VAR_2=${CODEBUILD_VAR_2}`. That will pass both variable to the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

Yet another amazingly annoying thing in Docker that doesn't actually need to be this difficult but for some reason is supremely complicated and/or non-intuitive.

command line:

```
docker build --build-arg My_AWS_ACCOUNT=${My_AWS_ACCOUNT}
```

Dockerfile:

```
ARG My_AWS_ACCOUNT
FROM ${My_AWS_ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someimage:latest
```